# Dialog notebook with multiple popup menus

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, dialog-window

I'm trying to create a user interface in *Mathematica*; the user will enter specified information, it will be processed, and then data will be inserted into a MySQL database. The pieces work independently but when I put them together, odd things happen.

So for example, this works:

```
Module[{ss, flist},
 flist = {"f1", "f2", "f3"};
 ss = First[flist];
 CreateWindow[DialogNotebook[{
    PopupMenu[Dynamic[ss], flist],
    ChoiceButtons[{"Enter", "Cancel"}, {DialogReturn[{Print["ss: ", ss]}]}]}]];
];
```

But the following, which seems to be substantially identical, does not. Specifically, if the user doesn't select something new from the popup menus, the variables never get initialized.

```
Module[{ss, flist, ci, clist},
 flist = {"f1", "f2", "f3"};
 clist = {"c1", "c2", "c3"};
 ss = First[flist];
 ci = First[clist];
 CreateWindow[DialogNotebook[{
    PopupMenu[Dynamic[ss], flist],
    PopupMenu[Dynamic[ci], clist],
    ChoiceButtons[{"Enter", "Cancel"}, {DialogReturn[{Print["ss: ", ss, ". ci: ", ci]}]}]}]];
 ];
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the it is expected and it happens because after prompting a `DialogNotebook` the evaluation of Module is finished and a `Temporary` attribute of its variables is kicking in.

Why the first example works the second doesn't? I don't know but how a `Temporary` attribute works is not documented well.

---

- One way to make it work is to use *kernel blocking dialog* (`Input`, `DialogInput`, `ChoiceDialog`) to not finish `Module` before `DialogReturn[]`:

  ```
  Module[{ss, flist, ci, clist}, 
    flist = {"f1", "f2", "f3"};   clist = {"c1", "c2", "c3"};
    ss = First[flist];   ci = First[clist];

    DialogInput[
       Column@{
         PopupMenu[Dynamic[ss], flist], 
         PopupMenu[Dynamic[ci], clist], 
         ChoiceButtons[
             {"Enter", "Cancel"}, 
             {DialogReturn[{Print["ssd: ", ss, ". cid: ", ci]}]}
         ]
       }
    ];
  ]
  ```

  Notice the red syntax highlighting over `Dynamic[ss]` and `Dynamic[c1]`. It's because it's good habit to **not to use `Module's` variables inside `Dynamics` inner to them** [[1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcLM5xDRqHE/V0FghIKeO_QJ)]. Here it should not harm but I'd use the second approach anyway:
- Pass `Module's` variables to the `Dialog` and forget about old `Module`.

  ```
  Module[{ss, flist, ci, clist}, 
     flist = {"f1", "f2", "f3"}; clist = {"c1", "c2", "c3"};
     ss = First[flist]; ci = First[clist];

     CreateWindow[ DialogNotebook[ DynamicModule[
       {ssd = ss, cid = ci}
       ,
       Column@{
          PopupMenu[Dynamic[ssd], flist], 
          PopupMenu[Dynamic[cid], clist], 
          ChoiceButtons[
            {"Enter", "Cancel"}, 
            {DialogReturn[{Print["ssd: ", ssd, ". cid: ", cid]}]}
          ]
       }
      ]]];
     ]
  ```

---

[[1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcLM5xDRqHE/V0FghIKeO_QJ)] "Module variables should never appear inside Dynamics ... internal to that Module." - John Fultz